# Find release history when using Deployment-Slots

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines

We are using Azure CI/CD pipeline and have started publishing to deployment slots. After doing this change the publishing history is no longer updated, not in the production or staging slot. Is there any way to keep track on whats in production when using deployment slots?